# Spark DataFrame - .distinct() not working?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, distinct

I'm using the following code:

```
df = df.select(
            df.col("col").as("col1"),
            df.col("col_").as("col2");
df = df.select("*").distinct();
df= df.sample(true, 0.8).limit(300);
df= df.withColumn("random", lit(0));

df.show();
```

I want to select distinct rows, then take a sample and limit it to 300 records, however `df.show();` shows that there are duplicate rows all over the place. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show us something?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Show you what exactly? The data itself is confidential. But theere are complete dows that are duplicates, not sure what else you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assign to a new dataframe

```
val myDupeDF=myDF.select(myDF.col("EmpName"))
myDupeDF.show()
val myDistinctDf=myDF.select(myDF.col("EmpName")).distinct
myDistinctDf.show();
+-------+
|EmpName|
+-------+
|   John|
|   John|
|   John|
+-------+
```

After distinct

```
+-------+
|EmpName|
+-------+
|   John|
+-------+
```

**Update for all columns**
I choose all columns still it work for me. I am using spark 1.5.1

```
  val myDupeDF=myDF.select(myDF.col("*"))
    myDupeDF.show()
    val myDistinctDf=myDF.select(myDF.col("*")).distinct
    myDistinctDf.show();
```

Result:

```
+-----+-------+------+----------+
|EmpId|EmpName|Salary|SalaryDate|
+-----+-------+------+----------+
|    1|   John|1000.0|2016-01-01|
+-----+-------+------+----------+
```

-

Comment: The only problem is that I have like 30 columns, so naming them all in the select is cumbersome. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
df = df.select(
            df.col("col").as("col1"),
            df.col("col_").as("col2");
df = df.distinct();
df= df.sample(true, 0.8).limit(300);
df= df.withColumn("random", lit(0));

df.show();
```

But I think u need to mention a column name to perform distinct operation -

> df = df.select("COLUMNNAME").distinct();

Comment: I tried `df = df.distinct();` instead of `df = df.select("*").distinct();`, doesn't work. In my dataset I have like 30 columns, naming them all is madness.

Comment: Also, you don't need the column name for distinct. Documentation says:
`distinct()
Returns a new DataFrame that contains only the unique rows from this DataFrame.`